# Python - Why is result of CRC32(np.int64(1)) different to CRC32(np.int32(1))?

Tags: python, numpy, crc32, int64, int32

CRC32 comparisons in Python:

```
>>> zlib.crc32(np.int64(1)) == zlib.crc32(np.int32(1))
False

>>> np.int64(1) == np.int32(1)
True

>>> zlib.crc32(np.int64(1))
2844319735

>>> zlib.crc32(np.int32(1))
2583214201
```

The polynomial expression of 1, regardless of its int64 or int32 data type, should be the same and yet their CRC32 results are different.
I've tried many other numbers than 1 and the CRC32 of the int64 and int32 results still won't match.

Any help in clearing up this incredibly confusing issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: CRC runs over byte streams, not numbers.  One is (probably) doing CRC32(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) and the other is doing CRC32(1, 0, 0, 0) presuming Little Endian.

Comment: I see. Twisting my question a bit, assuming instead if my system is Big Endian, then zlib.crc32(np.int64(1)) == zlib.crc32(np.int32(1)) will return True, is this correct?

Comment: No.  CRC32 is length sensitive.  You can feed it as many zeros as you want and get (generally) different results, at least until you start hitting collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cbc32 works on bytes.

int32 is 4 bytes, `1` is `01 00 00 00`

int64 is 8 bytes, `1` is `01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

```
>>> zlib.crc32(np.int64(1)) == zlib.crc32(b''.join([np.int32(1), np.int32(0)]))
True
```